# MATLAB code to find distance and eccentricity in graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science, matlab

I was trying to find the distances between vertices in graphs. But as the number of vertices are increasing up to 25 vertices or more, its becoming a tedious job for me to calculate $distance$ and $eccentricity$.

Can I draw graphs in MATLAB and then calculate the $dist$ and $ecc$?

***For ex. What is the code if I want to draw $P_n$ and then the distances between vertices.***

I am very new to MATLAB. Started few days back only. Can anyone help me here.

**Edit : I want the code to draw the graph which are Undirected and non-weighted graphs. And also distance between every two vertices. Can I make the graph if I am taking adjacency matrix. Is it possible to make the graph when entries are like ordered pairs of adjacent vertices .**

I would be very thankful. thanks

Coding for any small graph like $P_3$ or $K_4$ will be helpful for me.

Comment: What is your input? An adjacency matrix? And by distance you mean shortest path between vertices?

Comment: distance is the shortest path between vertices. Is it possible to find distance and eccentricity by giving an input in the form of adjacency matrix?

Comment: Do i need to install any package other than matlab?

Comment: Do you specifically want to render it, or are you really just interested in calculations?

Comment: @Lucas  I am basically interested in calculations..... calculation of distances between vertices and eccentricities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work out graph distance use Dijkstra's algorithm which is available for MATLAB [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36140-dijkstra-algorithm)

```
% K4 does not have edge weights in its definition
%  Make them all 1

K4 = ones(4) - eye(4) % Matrix of ones minus identity

% Find distance between nodes 1 and 2
[cost, route] = dijkstra(K4, 1, 2)

% Find the eccentricity using algorithm below

ecc = eccent(K4)
```

You could download and install MATLABS graph theory toolbox (can't give a link on SE), which has the functions `grEccentricity`
and `grShortPath`
but it requires the optimization toolbox, which is propriety. So assuming you don't have the money to pay for a toolbox, here is an eccentricity function. There are surely faster algorithms than this one ($O(E^2)\times O(\text{dijkstra})$), but it is really simple - check every pair (assumes undirected edges).

```
function e = eccent(g)
    e = 0;

    for i=1:length(g)
        for j=1:(i-1) % only i < j

            % Find distance between nodes
            [new_e, path] = dijkstra(g, i, j);

            % If this distance is bigger than saved distance,
            %  make e the new distance

            if new_e > e
                e = new_e;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

should work, but I don't own MATLAB to test it, you will need to put in a file called "eccent.m" in your working directory, because, well, it's MATLAB and that's how it works.

---

A function for $K_n$ is:

```
function g = Kn(n)
    % Puts a distance of one for all edges
    g = ones(n) - eye(n);
end
```

and for $P_n$ is

```
function g = Pn(n)
    % Pn is a set of nodes like 1--2--3--4
    %  the edges are length one for neighbouring nodes
    %  so the matrix is tridiagonal with entries 1 on the -1, and 1 diagonals

    g = diag(ones(n-1,1),1) + diag(ones(n-1,1),-1);
end
```

and the cyclic graphs just add a one to the antidiagonal corners

```
function g = Cn(n)
    g = Pn(n);
    g(n,1) = 1;
    g(1,n) = 1;
end
```

These would need to be in files "Kn.m", "Pn.m" and "Cn.m" respectively.

---

To make a *directed* graph for a list of pairs of the form:

```
[[a,b];[c,d]...]
```

then

```
function g = directed(pairs, n)
    % make graph with no edges
    g = zeros(n);

    % add each edge
    for p=1:length(pairs)
       i = pairs(p,1);
       j = pairs(p,2);

       g(i,j) = 1;

    end
end
```

and for an *undirected* graph

```
function g = undirected(pairs)

    % make graph with no edges
    g = zeros(n);

    % add each edge
    for p=1:length(pairs)
       i = pairs(p,1);
       j = pairs(p,2);

       g(i,j) = 1;
       g(j,i) = 1;

    end
end
```

Comment: $P_3$ is path graph. here you can have the details. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PathGraph.html I will go through reply. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I would advise looking at the results of the graph functions for various $n$ to see what they do.

Comment: @monalisa I will fix it for your edit.

Comment: @monalisa As I said, I don't own MATLAB, so it's untested, but I'm 99% sure it's correct.

Comment: ok :-) I will this in lab... I don't have matlab in my system... thanks a lot though for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use this http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphshortestpath.html or google "shortest path code in Matlab" and find other options.
This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222429/graph-theory-shortest-path-problem-via-matrix-operations-in-matlab) might also help you.

Comment: But this coding is for directed graphs. I want for undirected graphs

Comment: No, it is for all kind of graph.

Comment: i would be grateful if you may provide whole coding here for a very small graph. I am sorry to say I am not able to grasp things.